# How to find nearest div element using jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

my html:

```
<td class="result">
    <div id="main_title">
        <label for="textfield"></label>
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="<?php echo $row['leftpanelmaintitle']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div id="edit"><a href="#">EDIT</a></div>
    <div id="update"><a href="#">UPDATE</a></div>
</td>
```

my js:

```
$('#edit').click(function()
    {

        $('#main_title').show(1000,function(){
            $('#update').show();
            $('#textfield').focus();
            });
        })
```

i want to use common selector in the place of $('#main_title'). that is the address of previous div.

i tried;

```
$(this).click(function()
    {

        $(this).prev('div').show(1000,function(){
            $('#update1').show();
            $('#textfield').focus();
            });
        })
```

bt not working.

Comment: Don't invalidate your HTML by using the same id on multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#edit').click(function () {
    $(this).prev('#main_title').show(1000, function () {
        $('#update').show();
        $('#textfield').focus();
    });
});
```

Here, `$(this).prev('#main_title')` will give you the previous div with **ID** `main_title` to the currently clicked div with **ID** `edit`

**UPDATE**

You can add a class named `edit` to the edit button and do it like this:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().show(1000, function () {
        $('#update').show();
        $('#textfield').focus();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYxp3/)

Comment: ok its working,bt am clicking in the second edit button first update button also showing.how it avoid??

Comment: just add a class to update div to, same as we did for edit div and modify the "$('#update').show()" to "$(this).closest('.result').find('.update').show();"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$('id').children()` to get the previous div by writing the id of that present div.